# memory leak when not using WeakReference for Context member variable

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

Consider this class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Context mContext;

    public SomeClass(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Is it better to use

```
public class SomeClass {

    private WeakReference<Context> mContext;

    public SomeClass(Context context) {
        this.mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }
}
```

To avoid memory leaks? I'm under the impression that the Android system manages itself.

Comment: It depends on how you use `SomeClass`.

Comment: If you unbind the context meaning mContext = null on pause or anywhere else, then you should be fine. otherwise it's a leak unless you use WeakReference

Comment: Thnx! Didn't know this. A lot of people are doing it wrong then since I see it quite a lot.